# Stacking a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I am stuck on little problem with combining a list of dictionaries into one output.

I have got the following list of dictionaries:

```
listOfDicts = [{"name": "Andi", "toy": "puppet"}, {"name": "Andi", "toy": "monkey"},{"name": "Mum", "toy": "ape"}, {"name": "Mum", "toy": "sheep"}]
```

and I would like to have to following ouput so that for "name" I have got the "toy"s combined in one field. The final output should be:

```
finalDicts = [{"name": "Andi", "toy": "puppet, monkey"}, {"name": "Mum", "toy": "ape, sheep"}]
```

How can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: Should the order of the names remain the same?

Comment: I'd suggest do use lists to store the toys, not a single comma-separated string.

Answer (score 0):

A very procedural way to do it would be:

```
temp_store = {}
for element in listOfDicts:
    temp_store[element["name"]] = temp_store.get(element["name"], []) + [element["toy"]]
finalDicts = [{"name": element, "toy": ", ".join(temp_store[element])} for element in temp_store]
```

You can use `collections.OrderedDict` for `temp_store` if you want to keep the order.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to collect the items:

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for dct in listOfDicts:
    result[dct['name']].append(dct['toy'])

print(result)
# defaultdict(list, {'Andi': ['puppet', 'monkey'], 'Mum': ['ape', 'sheep']})
```

If you don't want `defaultdict`, the same can be done with a normal dictionary:

```
result = {}
for dct in listOfDicts:
    try:
        result[dct['name']].append(dct['toy'])
    except KeyError:
        result[dct['name']] = [dct['toy']]
```

Then you just need to create a list from these and `join` the lists:

```
resultlist = [{'name': key, 'toy': ', '.join(value)} for key, value in result.items()]
print(resultlist)
# [{'name': 'Andi', 'toy': 'puppet, monkey'}, {'name': 'Mum', 'toy': 'ape, sheep'}]
```

However because the intermediate dictionary is "unordered" the result could be arbitarly ordered `Mum` before `Andi`. You could use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to garantuee correct ordering. Then just use the approach I showed in the second code block to create it.